# Glass Mapper - "The given key was not present in dictionary"

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, glass-mapper

We're trying to configure Glass Mapper for our Sitecore 6.6 instance but came across this error when testing it out.

> [KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the
>   dictionary.]
>       System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +13763207
>       Glass.Mapper.AbstractService..ctor(String contextName) +99
>       Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService..ctor(Database database, String contextName) +55
>       Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreContext..ctor() +98
>       [Sublayout].Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in [Sublayout].ascx.cs:18
>       System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +109
>       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
>       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +165
>       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +165
>       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +165
>       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +165
>       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +165
>       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +165
>       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +165
>       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +4498

and the code calling this is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = new SitecoreContext();
        Model = context.GetCurrentItem<Article>();
    }
```

`Version 3.3.1.53` is installed (as we had issues with our version of Sitecore on 4.x versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen when context hasn't been loaded properly.

Make sure you deployed all the config's that comes with Glass eg:

```
Website\App_Config\Include\Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor.config
```

Also make sure you copied across all the .dll's that comes with Glass Installation.

Comment: Yes, that file does appear to be missing. Is there any reason why this would fail to come across with the nuget install?

Comment: Castle Windsor has been removed from GlassMapper v4, as you said you are on Version 3.3.1.53 it should get it from nuget install. Don't know what happened there.

Comment: The issue was due to the Glass.Mapper.Sc package being installed instead of Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor which has since been deprecated but is the only version Glass with an out of the box DI setup that works for Sitecore 6.6.

Comment: FWIW; the package can be found here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor